# pytorch installation in windows 7 32-bit sysytem

Tags: python, windows

I've installed Python Anaconda in Windows 7, but I can't install pytorch in system.

Does anyone have an how idea to install PyTorch in a Windows 7 32-bit system?

Comment: A quick search will lead to  [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/how-to-install-pytorch-in-windows). Always search before you ask.

Comment: @jdhao, A quick search of that page shows it gives absolutely no indication of whether pytorch can be run on a *32-bit* system. Always *read the question* before you respond.

Answer (score 2):

A few steps as described [here](https://pyshine.com/How-to-install-PyTorch-in-Windows-CPU-Version/) may help to install Pytorch in Windows considering a specific case of Python 3.6:

1. First, we need to install Shapely. For this download Shapely as Shapely-1.6.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely). For 32bit windows use this Shapely‑1.7.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

Then go to the directory where you have downloaded the whl file and then press SHIFT and right click and select open command prompt here and then execute this:
`pip install Shapely-1.6.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
For 32 bit:
`pip install Shapely‑1.7.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`

2. Secondly, we need to install Fiona. For this go to [Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pytorch) and download Fiona‑1.7.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl, or for 32 bit use this Fiona‑1.8.17‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

Then execute this command:
`pip install Fiona‑1.7.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`
For 32 bit:
`pip install Fiona‑1.8.17‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`

3. Third and final step is to download [PyTorch](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/enseignement/setup/)
   download and install the latest torch whl (for example torch-1.5.0+cpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) or using pip install torch
   For other Python or Torch Versions check the wheels [here](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/enseignement/setup/).

Comment: Hmmm, these are instruction for a 64-bit Windows... The question clearly states 32-bit windows...

Comment: Thanks for marking that, 32-bit windows instructions are updated as well

Comment: You... I like you. You even updated that blog of yours regarding the 32-bit scenario... You deserve a cookie.  :)

Comment: Oh, the links leading to "xavierdupre.fr" are broken, they've removed torch-0.4 and replaced it with a latest version!

Answer (score 1):

Official website offers lot of way to download PyTorch in different kinds of OS: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

[Take "pip" for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w30Vj.png)

You can see "amd64" in file name, which means it only works on 64bits computer.

Answer (score -1):

In the Command Window type

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch_legacy cuda80
```

(see [peterjc123 comment](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/494#issuecomment-350527200)), or

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

(see [Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python](http://pytorch.org)).