# Train Python Object Detection Model Strait Object's Images

Tags: python

as the title states, is there a way to build a object detection model (with a library pytorch or tensorflow) that trains straight from the objects picture. Here's an example. This is the inputted image.

[image: Clash Royale Battle Scene]
(A Clash Royale Battle Scene)

And say that I wanted it to detect a troop (Let's say the valkyrie with orange hair). I could train it with how you'd normally train it (put a box around it) and do a bunch of examples, but is there a way that I could just give it the valkyrie image (below)

[image]

And train it on that. For my situation, this will be much easier. Also I know that I said tensorflow before, but if possible I'd like not to use it as I have a 32bit system. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jack, what you're wanting to do is definitely possible. I'd recommend training a convolution neural network using pytorch (or an equivalent package that's [compatible with 32bit systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109783/pytorch-installation-in-windows-7-32-bit-sysytem)). What's you're experience with machine learning, specifically building neural networks?

Comment: This would be my first neural network, but I did do a little in Sklearn.

Comment: To do what you want to do is going to require reasonable knowledge in machine learning and I don't recommend this for a beginner. There are some great courses out there (coursera, stanford lagunita, etc) that can help you learn this topic for little/no fee. Also, I'm sure you could find a repos on github that have attempted to make the process of object detection more "push-button" like. Let me know if you have further questions. With that said, if left unedited, I think it would be best to close this question since it is broad and not specifically about coding.

Comment: @AustinA  What would this type of object recognition be called? I've googled stuff like "python train object detection model with object images" but it just brings up how you'd normally train a model.

Comment: I don't think this is a "special type" of object detection. [This](https://blog.paperspace.com/how-to-implement-a-yolo-object-detector-in-pytorch/) would be a good start, but I'm assuming you have the necessary knowledge in linear algebra, stats, and computer science to follow along.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems I am misunderstanding something.